# Buscar elementos en una lista

Tags: python

Seguro que lo que os propongo es muy básico, pero tengo un bloqueo con este problema....

Dice:

Tenemos una lista:

```
lst = [['apple', 'orange', 'banana'], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9.9, 10], ['green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'red']]
```

Usa "in" "not in" tests para determinar si el valor "yellow" está en la lista y asígnalo a la variable "yellow"

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si te obliga a usar `in` no te queda más remedio que recorrer la lista de listas y comprobar una a una:

```
yellow = False
for l in lst:
    if "yellow" in l:
        yellow = True
        return
```

El `return` tras encontrar `yellow` en la lista se hace para parar el bucle, pues ya no queremos que siga buscando.

Respecto al `not in` no entiendo... es decir, ¿se requiere a la inversa? si es así pues sería invirtiendo el código adjunto.

Comment: Resuelto!. Muchas gracias. Yo creo que la pregunta  no está muy bien formulada. Además  estaba recorriendo dos veces la lista de listas.

Answer (score 0):

Solo como curiosidad por si alguien más lo lee y quiere aprender otros patrones pythónicos (aunque estos patrones pueden considerarse "avanzados" por lo que seguramente no te servirían como respuesta al ejercicio, al usar cosas que no habrías dado aún):

```
yellow = any("yellow" in sublst for sublst in lst)
```

### Explicación

Lo que va dentro de los paréntesis es una *expresión generadora*. En el fondo se traduce en un generador sobre el cual es posible iterar. En cada iteración nos devolverá `False` o `True`, según sea falso o cierto que `"yellow" in sublst`. La variable `sublst` va tomando valores de los elementos de `lst` por lo que es una sublista de cada vez.

La función `any()` itera sobre su argumento, y tan pronto como encuentra un `True`, retorna `True` y no itera más. Sólo si agota el generador sin haber encontrado un `True`, retornará `False`.

Por tanto esa única línea hace lo que pedías.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Aunque como dices, no me sirve para este ejercicio, ya que me obligan a hacerlo de una forma concreta, me resulta muy útil para hacer lo más elegante.